# How to write a 2D array of floats in a file as bytes?

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point, byte, dataoutputstream

I have the following float array:

```
float[] arr = [ (1.2,2.3,2.4), (4.7,4.8,9.8) ]
```

and I wish to write it on a file through `DataOutputStream` in bytes. I have tried this so far:

```
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));

      for(int row = 0; row<arr.length; row ++) {
                for(int column = 0; column<arr[0].length; column++) {
                    out.writeByte(arr[row][column]);
                }
            }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
The method writeByte(int) in the type DataOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (float)
```

Normally, the same thing would work if `arr` and integer array was. Does somebody know how I could write each element of the array as byte in the file? Thanks in advance

Comment: In which version of Java this code compiles `float[] arr = [ (1.2,2.3,2.4), (4.7,4.8,9.8) ]`?

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeFloat(float)). `DataOutputStream` has a `writeFloat` method

Comment: @QBrute I want to store it as byte not as float

Comment: @hispanicprogrammer then what should `1.2` be represented as byte? A `float` in Java has a size of 4 bytes. Also have you read the linked documentation? `writeFloat` doesn't mean that there's a float value in your data. the "data" is always stored as bytes, so the method just takes the byte representation of your float and writes that to the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet is working:

```
// fix array declaration
float[][] arr = { {1.2f,2.3f,2.4f}, {4.7f,4.8f,9.8f} };

// use try-with-resources to close output stream automatically
try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("floats.dat"))) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < arr[row].length; column++) {
            out.writeFloat(arr[row][column]);
        }
    }
}
// resulting file has length 24 bytes

try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("float_bytes.dat"))) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < arr[row].length; column++) {
            out.writeByte((byte)arr[row][column]);
        }
    }
}
// resulting file has length 6 bytes
```

Comment: Hey! I want to write every iteam of the array as byte not as float

Comment: Hey! `byte` is an integer type of 1 byte with range [-128, 127] and `float` has 4 bytes with its format.  How do you want to press 4 bytes into 1?  Of course, you may cast float to byte and lose all fraction part and limit the values with mentioned byte range.